# ValueError: Found array with dim 34644. Expected 80841

Tags: python, numpy

I tried this tutorial to classify text within a new project: http://scikit-learn.org/stable/tutorial/text_analytics/working_with_text_data.html It helps us to automatically choose a suitable category for a given document, within our category tree.

But I receive an error when I try to create a loop, this is most of my classifier class:

```
import psycopg2
import psycopg2.extras

from sklearn.datasets import fetch_20newsgroups,load_files
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfTransformer
from sklearn.naive_bayes import MultinomialNB
from sklearn.pipeline import Pipeline
from sklearn import metrics
from random import randint
import settings


class Classifier(object):
    # Set Naive Bayes classifier
    nb_classifier = Pipeline([('vect', CountVectorizer()),
                              ('tfidf', TfidfTransformer()),
                              ('clf', MultinomialNB())])

    random = randint(2, 9)

    def __new__(cls):
        inst = object.__new__(cls)
        return inst

    # Constructor
    def __init__(self):
        # Start connection with database
        db_settings = "host='{}' dbname='{}' user='{}' password='{}'".format(settings.DB_HOST, settings.DB_TARGET, settings.DB_USER, settings.DB_PASS)
        self.conn = psycopg2.connect(db_settings)
        self.cursor = self.conn.cursor()

        print(randint(2, 9))

    # Get categorized data from db for training purposes
    def getCategories(self,parent):
        if parent == 0:
            self.cursor.execute("""SELECT "categories"."id", concat_ws(', ', products.name::text) AS ab  FROM "products"
                INNER JOIN "product_categories" ON "products"."id" = "product_categories"."product_id"
                INNER JOIN "categories" ON "product_categories"."category_id" = "categories"."id"
                WHERE "parent" = 0""")
        else:
            self.cursor.execute("""SELECT "categories"."id", concat_ws(', ', products.name::text) AS ab  FROM "products"
                INNER JOIN "product_categories" ON "products"."id" = "product_categories"."product_id"
                INNER JOIN "categories" ON "product_categories"."category_id" = "categories"."id"
                WHERE "categories"."id" IN (SELECT * FROM  (
                    WITH RECURSIVE relevant_taxonomy AS (
                            SELECT id
                            FROM categories
                            WHERE id = %s

                            UNION ALL

                            SELECT categories.id
                            FROM categories
                            INNER JOIN relevant_taxonomy ON relevant_taxonomy.id = categories."parent"
                            )
                    SELECT id FROM relevant_taxonomy
                ) AS subtree WHERE subtree.id != %s);""", (parent,parent,))
        return self.cursor.fetchall()

    # Train a classifier with train-data
    def train_classifier(self, classifier, train_data):
        ## train given classifier with given data
        trained_classifier = classifier.fit(train_data.data, train_data.target)

        return trained_classifier
```

And this is the classify file, where I use the "Classifier" class.
classify.py:

```
from traindata import Traindata
from classifier import Classifier
import numpy as np
from pprint import pprint


# Get all documents inside with category
def classify(cat, doc):
    # Create instance of classifier
    print('%r => %s' % (doc, cat))


    classifier = Classifier()
    rows = classifier.getCategories(cat)


    if not rows:
        print 'put document \n\n "%(1)s" \n\nin term_taxonomy id %(2)s' % {'1':doc, '2':cat}
        return None

    new_docs = [doc]

    # set target id's
    target_ids = []
    myset = set()
    for item in rows:
        if item[0] not in myset:
            target_ids.append(item[0])
            myset.add(item[0])

    # set train_data object
    train_data = Traindata()
    train_data.target_ids = target_ids;
    targets = [];

    for row in rows:
        train_data.data.append(row[1])
        index = train_data.target_ids.index(row[0])
        targets.append(index)
        print index
    #end setting train_data object#

    train_data.target = np.array(targets)

    #train_data.target_ids
    #train_data.target[:100]

    print train_data

    trained_classifier = classifier.train_classifier(classifier.nb_classifier, train_data)
    predicted_cats = classifier.predict(new_docs,trained_classifier)

    # pprint(zip(new_docs, predicted_cats))

    print(train_data.target_ids)

    for doc, category_index in zip(new_docs, predicted_cats):

        if not train_data.target_ids[category_index]:
            print 'not found'

        # print('%r => %s' % (doc, train_data.target_ids[category_index]))
        val = classify(train_data.target_ids[category_index],doc)

        return train_data.target_ids[category_index]


for doc in ['Loopschoen']:
    classify(0,doc)
```

I start executing the function once, by looping over the new docs as you can see at the bottom (`for doc in ['Loopschoen']:`), and as you can see I start with the categories with NO parents (0), which are the root nodes. The function returns a category where it wants to put the document in. But that's only the top level of the category tree, so I try to loop over the function again with this new value (so it tries to look for children of the chosen category), by returning the function again. At the end it will return the final category when it can't find any child categories anymore.

But every time the second loop fails with this error.
Error:

`ValueError: Found array with dim 46197. Expected 92394`

The loop is the only problem. Cause the first loop I receive a category number, number 2. Then if I run the script again with `classify(2,doc)` I receive the next category and after 4 or 5 runs I receive the message `put document "Loopschoen" in term_taxonomy id 20`. So it works, if I run the script over and over again and change the value. But the loop fails....

Anyone who knows why the loop fails?

EDIT 1:
We know it fails in the classifier class at: 
`trained_classifier = classifier.fit(train_data.data, train_data.target)`

But we cannot figure out why.

Comment: Please try to narrow down the issue, using a debugger/print statements/removing code/whatever. As it is now, you're just asking other people to debug your code for you - that's not this site's purpose.

Comment: I thought the error ```ValueError: Found array with dim 34644. Expected 80841``` tells some people more than it does to me ;) We know on which line it goes wrong, but we don't know why..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the problem, I had to reset the array inside the loop. It was just adding values to train_data.data so the number differed from train_data.target:

`train_data = Traindata()
train_data.data = []`

It expected train_data.target to have a length of 80841, cause train_data.data contained 80841 items (items from the previous loop as well).